# Compensation over postponed and not cancelled flight

Tags: united-kingdom, air-travel, compensation

My flight got delayed twice and when we got onboard we have been told that it got postponed for the next day. That is total 18 hours. We have not gotten any confirmation email, there was no representative at the airport. We have not been given the option for an alternative flight or even accommodation. We have only been given a 4 pound and then a 16 pound voucher. The airport cannot do much about it and their customer service is just fooling around saying that we should book a hotel or another flight and then claim the money from their website.

What is the immediate actions we can take? They say that the flight is not shown as postponed or cancelled in their system.

Comment: From using pounds I assume this is in the UK? Google 'European air passenger rights' I think they should still apply to you but better read it for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The information you have received is basically correct

Your rights are detailed [here](https://www.caa.co.uk/passengers/resolving-travel-problems/delays-and-cancellations/delays/).

> … they must provide:
>
> - A reasonable amount of food and drink (often provided in the form of vouchers)

> - A means for you to communicate (often by refunding the cost of your calls)
> - Accommodation, if you are re-routed the next day (usually in a nearby hotel)
> - Transport to and from the accommodation (or your home, if you are able to return there)

> Sometimes airlines are unable to arrange care and assistance for all passengers. This can happen when staff are stretched during major disruptions.
> If this happens, in our view you have the right to organise reasonable care and assistance yourself, then claim the cost back later. If you end up paying for things yourself, keep every receipt and do not spend more than is reasonable. Airlines are unlikely to refund you for things like luxury hotels or alcohol. Some will provide guidance on reasonable costs.
> You are also entitled to compensation if the flight lands more than 5 hours late or you can cancel for a full refund if the take off is delayed more than 5 hours.

Comment: Considering it was a long haul flight that got delayed 24 hours, I have applied for a refund. How long do the airliners have to compensate?

Comment: They actually asked us to checkin again the next day, after we were told that the flight got postponed for the next day. I assume it was a cancellation and not a postponement. That implies we are entitled to two compensations as there were two delays. Also, we were not given any option for a hotel that night.